# Convert list with duplicate values to dataframe

Tags: python

I have two lists, one of them contains duplicate values:

```
list1 = ['1','2','3','1','2','3','1','2','3']
list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```

I want the data in excel, but I can't convert them into a dictionary because the dictionary doesn't support duplicate values.
I am fine even if I get this type of data in Excel:

```
1  2  3
a  b  c
d  e  f
g  h  i
```

Actually, the data is repeating(a,d,g,j,m ... will come under header 1, and b,e,h and so on under 2 and similarly for 3 also) but I am not sure how to do it and I can't even think of anything to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to transform the data into a dictionary:

```py
list1 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
list2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]

result = {}
for key, value in zip(list1, list2):
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

print(result)
# Outputs {1: ['a', 'd', 'g'], 2: ['b', 'e', 'h'], 3: ['c', 'f', 'i']}
```

Then use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to write the data to a CSV file, which the Excel can read:

```py
import csv

with open('output.csv') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(result.keys())
    writer.writerows(zip(*result.values()))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little hacky but should work

```
data = {} 
for x, y in zip(list1, list2): 
    try: 
        data[x].append(y) 
    except: 
        data[x] = [y]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not convert them to a single dictionary, but you can convert them to a list of multiple dictionaries.

```py
>>> [{k:v for k,v in zip(list1[i:i+n+1],list2[i:i+n+1])} for i in range(0,len(list1),n)]

[{1: 'd', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}, {1: 'g', 2: 'e', 3: 'f'}, {1: 'g', 2: 'h', 3: 'i'}]
```

Or, you can just use `defaultdict` from `collections` module:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k].append(v)
    

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
>>> df
   1  2  3
0  a  b  c
1  d  e  f
2  g  h  i
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can fit these lists into a dictionary. Just have the column number as a key and fit the appropriate elements into a list that is this key's value.

`dict = {1: [a,d,g], 2: [b,e,h], 3: [c,f,i] }`